# Any way to implement dynamic_cast on a DelphiInterface to obtain underlying objects class?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I am writing code to implement a common set of capabilities across different back-end systems.  (For example raising a sales order in different order processing systems).  I have abstracted the capabilities and have defined Delphi style Interfaces for these.  To allow staged implementation in different back end systems each system can support different blocks of functionality.  (For example the 'raise sales order' functionality).  So there is a core API interface which allows us to find out what capabilities (there is a capability interface) are installed, and obtain a specific named capability (where each named capability has its own interface).

So I am implementing as a series of object classes that implement both the IAPICapability interface and a specific function interface (for example the IAPIRaiseSalesOrder interface).  The IAPICapability interface has a method CanInstallTo which determines if a particuler functionality can be loaded into the Core API interface.

What I want to be able to do is determine if the API That I am trying to install into is the correct type of API for this module.

I originally specified passing an IInterface to CanInstallTo, but I cannot find any way to cast this to an object so that I can use a dynamic_cast to determine if it's what that class expects to plug into.

Looking at the documentation the DelphiInterface includes operator overloading to obtain the underlying pointer.  I expect that this sould effectively be an object pointer with a vtable in C++ terms - because in C++ terms Interfaces are implemented with multiple inheritance.

However I haven't managed to find code that can cast this to an object pointer.

I can include a 'Signature' in the IAPIInterface and check that, but this would not allow me to use the same object class to implement multiple types of backends (which using interfaces should allow me to do).  I could allow a 'SupportsSignature' method to implement multiple types of backends ... but if I have an object with class inheritence I should be able to use dynamic_cast.

For now I have changed the specification to pass a TComponent * to CanInstallTo, but this mandates using a TComponent as a base class which is not a probem but doesn't sit with the general concept of using abstract interfaces.

This code does not work, but gives an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
bool TAPICapabilityModule::CanInstallTo(_di_IInterface Target)
{
bool              blRc=false;
TWantedAPIType  * pAPI;

  if((pAPI=dynamic_cast<TWantedAPIType *>(Target))!=NULL)
  { // continue with other checks if needed
    if(pAPI->Capability[MY_CAPABILTY_ID]==NULL)
    {
      blRc=true;
    }
  }
  return(blRc);
}
```

I am using TComponent * as the core API Implementation for now, but I wondered if anybody knows how to complete this entirely with interfaces?

Comment: RTTI might be useful?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  Unfortunately I have discovered sume bugs with the clang compilers where Delphi RTTI does not properly pass through the class layer when inheriting from a Delphi base class in C++.  I have some open support with Embarcadero for this, but it makes me very hesitant to rely on it. -- How could I access RTTI based on a _di_IInterface?

Comment: Isn't it almost always a sign of broken design to try to get an implementing object from an interface

Comment: @David - there is certainly a school of thought that would say that.  Just as there is a school of thought that says that multiple inheritance should never be used.  However what I am trying to do seems to me to be sound.  Interface 1 (the API) can have mutiple sets of interface 2 (the capabilities) installed into it.  the API is given an abstracted interface to install, and asks that interface if it can be installed into it.  This allows the API not to know about all of the capabilities that might be installed.  The capability, on the other hand, does need to know about the API.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but isn't this what IUnknown.QueryInterface is for? To see if the (underlying instance of) the interface also supports certain other interfaces? If the capability instances need to have a specific API instance, it sounds to me like it's better to give them that instance directly, instead of them having to fetch it through that interface.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, QueryInterface can look for a specific interface being implemented - which would require a definition of a new Interface (which are intended to be abstract and multi purpose) simply to define that it's a specific class.  Hence the desire to use dynamic_cast which works on the class hierarchy instead.  (I already use QueryInterface to obtain the capabilities available from the API that has them installed into it.  They are actually interfaces on a different object, but the caller does not need to be awware of that because they are interfaces.)

Comment: It's not an interface if it exposes implementation

Comment: @David - Thanks for your comments. From a C++ point of view a class implementing interfaces uses multiple inheritence where all but one of the base classes are pure virtual classes. I'm not asking to expose implementation, I'm asking if an object inherits from a class. I don't have a Delphi background and it may be that I'm not understanding something becasue of that. The documentation says the DelphiInterface wraps a pointer (to an object) that inherits from classes (or does it? - I may be wrong here because I don't know the Delphi). Is it possible to get that pointer and dynamic_cast it?

Comment: "I'm asking if an object inherits from a class" , is exposing implementation. Because class inheritance is implementation inheritance. Unless the class is pure virtual. But I don't think your classes are pure virtual, and anyway in delphi instead of a pure virtual class you would use an interface. Of course, you can use `is` or `as` to query for or cast to classes in Delphi, but it's pretty much always a sign of poor design. Of course this question isn't really a c++ question, or even a Delphi question, it's a pure C++Builder question.

Comment: @David "It's a pure C++Builder question" is correct, but it's to do with how multiple inheritance is implemented for Delphi derived classes which is Delphi specific. As I don't have years of Delphi experience I am asking for help. C++ allows dynamic_cast on a (pure virtual) pointer to an implementation class. An abstract interface (pure virtual class) can have a method CanInstallTo(abstract base class pointer). Making one-off interfaces or implementing a signature property makes the interface non-generic. If I can dynamic_cast (inside the implementation) I can keep abstract interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered a template helper function that will do exactly what I have asked for. I am running Rio (10.3.1) and it's implemented in the system file systobj.h - this should be included by <System.hpp> (which in turn is probably included by just about everything that uses the RTL).

The relevant code in this file (which does exactly what I was looking for, a dynamic_cast on the wrapped object pointer)

```cpp
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Object <-> Interface cast helpers
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  struct __declspec(uuid("{CEDF24DE-80A4-447D-8C75-EB871DC121FD}")) __IObjCastGUIDHolder;

  template <typename DESTOBJ>
  DESTOBJ* _interfaceToObjectCast(IInterface* src)
  {
    if (src)
    {
      TObject *obj = 0;
      src->QueryInterface(__uuidof(__IObjCastGUIDHolder), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&obj));
      return dynamic_cast<DESTOBJ*>(obj);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

It can be used like this:

```cpp
bool TAPICapabilityClass::CanInstallTo(_di_IInterface Target)
{
bool              blRc=false;
TWantedAPIType  * pAPI;

  if((pAPI=dynamic_cast<TWantedAPIType>(Target))!=NULL)
  { // continue with other checks if needed
    if(pAPI->Capability[MY_CAPABILTY_ID]==NULL)
    {
      blRc=true;
    }
  }
  return(blRc);
}
```

From the perspective of the consuming application it is still all abstract interfaces like this:

```cpp
void TApplicationUnit::InstallCapability(TComponent *pAPI, TObject *pCapability)
{
_di_IAPICore        diAPI;
_di_IAPICapability  diCapability

  if( (System::Sysutils::Supports(pAPI, _uuidof(IAPICore), (void **)(&diAPI))) &&
      (System::Sysutils::Supports(pCapability, _uuidof(IAPICapability), (void **)(&diCapability))) &&
      (diCapability->CanInstallTo(diAPI)) )
  {
    diAPI->InstallCapability(diCapability);
  }
}
```

I have yet to get to a point where I can properly test the code (but it compiles).

There are some valid points in the comments as to whether casting an abstract 
interface to an object is good design. As I see this in terms of C++ multiple inheritance I expect to be able to dynamic_cast between abstract types. The design goals of the use case require the implementation of the various back office systems are hidden from the consuming applications, but splitting the functionality between multiple classes requires that the implementing classes know about the other classes in that same implementation (but not necessarily their internal workings).

From the little I know of Delphi there is a loose parallel where Delphi classes in the same unit being able to access each other in ways that other classes can't simply because they're in the same unit. There are many instances where you want abstract interfaces to be presented to consuming classes, but internal to your implementing classes you need more detailed knowledge of the other classes.